# robocopy: Fails to synchronize really two directories

Tags: robocopy, thunderbird

I'm using robocopy to synch directories very easily as one easy step for backup & recovery. Recently I've detected by a 1:1 compare tool that sometimes there are binary differences between the synched directories. Affected are files with same name (clear), size and date. Examples are some *.db and *.sqllite files in Thunderbird portable. I've checked carefully, that at the time running robocopy and later running the compare

- thunderbird portable is not running.
- there is no lock anywhere in the directory tree.
- all other programs listed on taskmanager are stopped (except DOS-box running the script which is calling robocopy).
- the script and the active path in the DOS-box are not in the compared directory tree.

Sure it is strange that thunderbird portable does not change timestamp of the changed files but this is another topic.

The syntax of the used robocopy command is:

```
robocopy h:\ K:\ /W:3 /R:5 /MIR /XD H:\RECYCLER "H:\System Volume Information"
```